# SSRS2012 The permissions granted to user ' are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I already:

1. Disabled UAC
2. Run IE as Admin
3. Added my local Reporting Services server to the list of trusted sites

However, I still get this error:

> SSRS2012 The permissions granted to user ' are insufficient for performing this operation

Although no need to enter username & password, still show the following

baby-pc/ReportServer - /

---

---

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 11.0.2100.60

Answer (score 0):

This is talking about Sql Server permissions. It has nothing to do with the local machine at all, and therefore nothing to do with UAC or Internet Explorer. Messing about with those will have no effect at all, as you've seen. You may has well put those things back how they where.

What you need to do instead is log in to Sql Server (using a tool like Sql Server Management Studio) with an account that has the ability to change permissions (such as the `sa` account, but hopefully you have a non-sa account that can do this as well) and **grant** your account the ability to use reporting services and select from any tables used in your reports.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you entered invalid credentials previously. Try to open the reporting service in FireFox and enter your valid credentials. If you have success with it, tune the group policy on the local machine for not storing user credentials. Do the next steps:

1. Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->internet Explorer->Internet Control Panel->Security Page
2. Select the required zone
3. In this folder find the option "Logon options"
4. Set up that as "Enabled" and set up "Logon options" to "Authomatic logon with current username and password" or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, try to login with firefox, but still does not work ,same error message

Comment: Could you attach the list of your user security settings and error screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Even I had faced this issue. But it was resolved when I added the particular user to Administrator group.